# Какой CSS-препроцессор выбрать для изучения и работы?

Tags: css, sass, less, scss

Хочу изучить CSS-препроцессор, для того, чтобы ускорить работу над проектами.
Нужен совет от тех, кто использует CSS-препроцессоры (LESS/SASS) при вёрстке.

Comment: less лучше читается, да и учить нового минимум - css подобный. sass крут, но спустя некоторое время, приходится вникать в собственный код. Но это если 'по верхам' .

Comment: Но SASS развивается быстрее, насколько мне известно, и функционал богаче. Мне реально нужно разобраться. Нужно учить тонну информации, или минимум - не важно.

Comment: Нет там тонн нигде, за вечер проглатывается. Вопрос больше в настройке окружения для удобной работы. И легкости поддержки своего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По большей части возможностей LESS и SASS сейчас очень близки. Так что на начальном этапе, что вам больше нравится, то и пробуйте. Для начальных потребностей вам хватит с головой и на очень долго.

Далее, когда вы уже освоитесь с одним из препроцессоров, переключиться на другой, чтобы попробовать, вам не составит труда.

Касательно именно SASS, я советую вам пользоваться его "диалектом" SCSS, так как он в целом похож на CSS и полностью с ним совместим.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону Stylus (просто) или postcss (просто и расширяемо).

А насчёт функционала, от десятиэтажных конструкций на препроцессорах начинает болеть голова ещё на этапе написания кода.